# Tempory file share

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, download

Hi i am building an ruby on rails application.I wants to share an attachment for a maximum of one hour only,thereafter that particular link must be deactivated.
is that possible to achieve this without doing any **CRON job**?

My requirement is user can upload attachments and they can share the encrypted URL.the maximum validity of that URL will be one hour.

I want to know that whether it is possible by without creating any **CRON job**? if yes please help me ?

Comment: Either: create a an id for the URL (a path param effectively), and store the timeout against whichever model controls the download. Or: include the timeout information in the encrypted (or hashed) data. You should explain some more (with simplified code) about how you are currently providing downloads, to get an answer that works best for you.

Comment: Thanks @NeilSlater it's a simple carrier-wave file upload which is stored in my local application folder. And i just encrypting that url using **bit.ly**, and this is the  [http://bit.ly/1ep4FzI] encrypted url.my requirement is very simple i don't wants to store the url or CRON jobs to make the attachment deactivated.once the user upload the document the above encrypted URL need to be valid for one hour only after that user should not access the url to download the document.

Answer (score 1):

you can use application controller helper `before_filter`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :check_expire

  def check_expire
    UrlLink.active.where('expire_time <= ?' Time.now).find_each do |url|
      url.deactive!
    end if UrlLink.active.any?
  end
end
```

model

```
class UrlLink < AB
  scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }

  def deactive!
    update(active: false)
  end
end
```

but this work slow if you have large db.

Comment: Thanks @Monk_Code. It is a file path. it will be server from public folder as a attachment. Is that possible for me to add before_filter for this?