# temporary file access using carrierwave rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, carrierwave, file-access

Hi I am a ROR developer and developing an ROR application where user can upload file and share the URL to download.

- I am using **carrierwave** for file upload and **storing the file in my application (not in AWS)**.
- I want to give permission for the user to access the upload file only for a certain period of time **(for ex:1 hour).**

please help me to achieve this without creating any **cron jobs** or **before_filter** method?

I found AWS has default feature for this but I am not storing the file in AWS S3. I am storing it in my local application folder, so please guide me how I can achieve this.

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results [dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361550/tempory-file-share/21361689#21361689)

Comment: @Monk_Code i am **not using AWS(s3)**. i wants to achieve this without using AWS. i am storing file in application folder itself. and looking for a better solution to avoid creating any **crone** or **before filter method** in rails.

Comment: @ferdy can you please provide us with what worked for you